# Is it possible with espresso to test an overlay in an application?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I got the task to write an autotest to check the overlay in the developed application.
The problem is that espresso doesn't see the overlay elements. In fact, they are on the screen, but I cannot check them. Does anyone know a workaround or solution to this issue?
Thanks!